# How do I combine to while loops so that I get the same output as I do with two while loops?

Tags: java

I have to redesign a program so that only one loop is used to determine

> every even and odd number between 50 -100.

```
public class Practice_6_3
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int even = 50;
    int odd = 51;

    System.out.print ("Even numbers between 50 and 100: \t");
    while (even <= 100)
    {
        System.out.print(even + ", ");
        even += 2;
    }

    System.out.print ("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: \t");
    while (odd <= 100)
    {
        System.out.print(odd + ", ");
        odd += 2;
    }
    }        
}
```

The output is:
Even numbers between 50 and 100:

```
50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100,
```

Odd numbers between 50 and 100:

```
51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99,
```

I can't figure out how to combine the while loops while keeping the same output format.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You'd just have to buffer everything that way.

Comment: The only way to keep the exact same format is to store the numbers somewhere (list or array) and then output everything at once at the end. However, I'm fairly certain that isn't the point of the exercise.

Comment: What's wrong with having two loops? Is a single loop a requirement of the task you've been set?

Comment: Yeah, It's part of the requirement to make it into a single loop.

Comment: @Runth Seems a completely pointless exercise - your code is better. You can do it by building up the output in a pair of StringBuilders, then printing them both at the end.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to build both lists of values in your loop, you could do it with a pair of [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) instances to record your `even` and `odd` values. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int even = 50;
    StringJoiner evens = new StringJoiner(", ");
    StringJoiner odds = new StringJoiner(", ");
    while (even <= 100) {
        evens.add(String.valueOf(even));
        if (even + 1 <= 100) {
            odds.add(String.valueOf(even + 1));
        }
        even += 2;
    }

    System.out.printf("Even numbers between 50 and 100: \t%s%n", evens);
    System.out.printf("Odd numbers between 50 and 100: \t%s%n", odds);
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
Even numbers between 50 and 100:    50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100
Odd numbers between 50 and 100:     51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99
```